# find nlargest ID for a value for each date

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, finance

I am looking for the 10 IDs that have the highest a value at each date.

[image: df]

```
for date in df:
    a = df.nlargest(10, ['a'])
    Top_performer.append(a[['ID','Renta','Date']])
```

as output I would like the IDs and their 'renta' for each date

I'm bothering you for something pretty simple I guess but I'm stuck! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

1. Groupby date
2. On each date, find the 10 largest values for "Renta"
3. Give a proper format to the output

Code:

```
>>> df.groupby("Date").apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(10, "Renta")).reset_index(drop=True))
```